# Get the Path of a file with the Uri

Tags: android

I am unable to get the path of the file with its given URI.

I have a video application that plays a video according to the path it reads from an EditText.

I created a browse button that allows me to open the built in file explorer using ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

I want that whatever video I click on in the file explorer the path automatically gets set to my EditText.

Im lost in the part where I call my onActivityResult

```
    public Boolean onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == RECEIVE_DATA){
     Uri uriEnd = data.getData(); 
    //here I am unsure of how to get the Path with the given Uri
    //I am using SDK Build 24 Nougat
    }
    }
```

If I call uriEnd.getPath(); I get a weird path

I know this question has been asked multiple times and I have taken a look at the responses but even with the suggestions given the path is never correct.

Comment: Can I recommend you this library? https://github.com/Angads25/android-filepicker I have used it and it solved my file issues

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to get the path of the file with its given URI.

A `Uri` is not a file.

> I created a browse button that allows me to open the built in file explorer using ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not necessarily involve any sort of "file explorer".

> If I call uriEnd.getPath(); I get a weird path

`getPath()` on a `Uri` only has meaning if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. The scheme of your `Uri` is `content`, most likely. The path will be meaningless to you and the user. There is little value in showing it to the user, and there is even less value in putting it in an `EditText` to be edited (since the edited result is unlikely to point to anything).

So, I suggest that you come up with another UI, one that does not involve showing the `Uri` from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to the user.

Comment: so basically im trying to get a browse button that opens up the built in file explorer. Im able to do everything except I cant wrap my head around how I can get the path of the file the user picks. If the way im doing it is incorrect please let me know what would be the correct way. This just seemed like the most straightforward approach.

Comment: @AlejandroSoto: "im trying to get a browse button that opens up the built in file explorer" -- there is no "built in file explorer". The closest thing is the Storage Access Framework UI, and that explores things that are not local files (Google Drive, network file servers, etc.). "Im able to do everything except I cant wrap my head around how I can get the path of the file the user picks" -- that is because the user is not picking a file.

Comment: @AlejandroSoto: If you want to limit the user to local files on the filesystem, [use a library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created) to embed your own "file explorer"-style UI into your app.

Comment: Yes I am referring to the Storage Access Framework UI. My issue Is how can I save the path of the file that is selected on the Storage Access Framework UI. What I did was start an intent and wait for the result but the data that is received I store as a URI. I did this since most people seemed to take this approach.

Comment: @AlejandroSoto: The `Uri` *is* the "path". And, if you are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, there is no value in saving the `Uri`, because you cannot access that content again later. Such a `Uri` is like an `https` URL to an authenticated Web site -- it works, but for a short period of time. If you want longer-term access to the content, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, then use `ContentResolver` and `takePersistableUriPermissions()` to request long-term access. Then, you can save the `Uri` (e.g., in a file, in `SharedPreferences`) and use it in the future, until the user deletes or moves the content.

Comment: @AlejandroSoto: Again, the Storage Access Framework UI provides access to more than just local files. It provides access to Google Drive, network file servers, and anything else that the user wants based on available storage providers. Any app can implement a `DocumentsProvider` and show up in the Storage Access Framework UI. My guess is that other online file services will offer this, and I could write one tomorrow. Plus, the user can pick local files that you cannot access directly (e.g., on removable storage).

Comment: All im trying to do is use the Storage Access Framework UI to allow the user to select and mp4 file. When the user selects an mp4 file i want the path of the video selected to be returned so that it can be displayed in an EditText in my app. I am no professional, It sounds like it would be very easy but I cant figure out how to go about this.

Comment: @AlejandroSoto: And I keep telling you that what you want is not possible using the Storage Access Framework. What if the user chooses an MP4 from Google Drive? Or from Dropbox? Or from a file server? If you do not want to deal with those things, stop using the Storage Access Framework, and [use a file-picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created).